# What's the difference between 'access token' and 'code' in Instagram API?

Tags: api, token, instagram

In using Instagram API, when I login with my Instagram ID, my url is like this : 'http://ec2-54-92-53-75.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/instagram_about_token/example/?code=34cde9ac55c047918e4973c9591595cb'

Actually, I set redirect URL as 'http://ec2-54-92-53-75.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/instagram_about_token/example/', so as a result of login, '?code=34cde9ac55c047918e4973c9591595cb' this was added.

Is this an access token of Instagram?? I'm not sure right now because in API console of Instagram, the request is something like this :
"GET /v1/users/self/feed?access_token=1470328514.1fb234f.09a36e85629645fe8115c369202ec012 HTTP/1.1"
As you see, the access token is added like '?access_token=~~~~',

so I want to know whether '?code=~~~' on my website means that I got an access token on my website. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in URL **is not** the access token you want, but it is **required** to get it. The whole process is good described on *Instagram Developer Documentation*: http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

> **Step Three: Request the access_token**
>
> In the previous step, **you’ll have received a code which you’ll have to
>   exchange in order to receive an access_token** for the user. In order to
>   make this exchange, you simply have to POST this code, along with some
>   app identification parameters to our access_token endpoint. Here are
>   the required parameters:
>
> **client_id**: your client id
>
> **client_secret**: your client secret
>
> **grant_type**: authorization_code is currently the only supported value
>
> **redirect_uri**: the redirect_uri you used in the authorization request.
>   Note: this has to be the same value as in the authorization request.
>
> **code**: the exact code you received during the authorization step.
>
> For example, you could request an access_token like so:

```
curl \-F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
     -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
     -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
     -F 'redirect_uri=YOUR-REDIRECT-URI' \
     -F 'code=CODE' \https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

> If successful, this call will return a neatly packaged OAuth Token that
>   you can use to make authenticated calls to the API. We also include
>   the user who just authenticated for your convenience:
>
> {
>       "access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
>       "user": {
>           "id": "1574083",
>           "username": "snoopdogg",
>           "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
>           "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg"
>       } }